Matrix representation of Clifford algebra elements
Hello,I am learning Clifford algebra as a preliminary step to studying the Dirac equation. The gamma matrices obey specific rules as elements of Clifford algebra: they square to either the identity matrix or the identity matrix multiplied by -1. I have a few questions:Is it always possible to represent all the special elements of a given Clifford algebra as matrices?How can one determine the minimum matrix size required for a given algebra?Will the matrix elements be real, complex, or something else?If the matrix elements are complex or something else, is it possible to increase the matrix size to ensure that all elements are real?Is there an algorithm to find all special elements matrix representation? It would be interesting, if there was iterative algorithm that you build simpler algebra first like Cl(1,0) or Cl(0,1) and then apply some rules to their matrix representation to obtain more complex algebras in steps.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

What do you mean by "special element" of the Clifford algebra?

Unfortunately, mods here don't like questions they can't understand. In short, matrix representations of Clifford algebras can be constructed by using something resembling a Fast Fourier transform (or, more appropriately, Hadamard-Walsh transform). You can refer to Chapter 5 of "A generalized FFT for Clifford algebras" by P.Leopardi for more info.
